# Java XML Parse - Remove First Tag

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jdk1.7

I would like to delete a few Tags from my XML string. It sounds simple, and I'm sure it its, but I'm having problems deleting the main Tag and keeping the SubTags inside.

Here is an example:

```
<Tag1 version = "">
    <SubTag1>
    </SubTag1>
    <SubTag2>
    </SubTag2>
</Tag1>
```

I would like to keep only the "SubTag2" and everything inside it.

Which is the best way to approach this?

I tried using REGEX to delete SubTag1, but I found here that this is never a good solution in XML:

```
result = result.replaceAll("<SubTag1>[\\s\\S]*?</SubTag1>","");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shold create an xml class and map your xml to this class. Then make the changes you need to the generated object from the class and then create the xml again. Here is a link to generate the java class : https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-java-converter

Comment: Hi @Filip123go, the link you passed is pretty interesting, but this solution is not what I'm finding, because I want to keep everything inside "SubTag2", but I don't need to know which nodes has, and these could change by time.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSoup (https://jsoup.org/) or another library to parse your string.
Then you can access the DOM tree and extract only the part with the specific tag.

It would look like this:

```
String xml = "<Tag1 version = \"\"><SubTag1></SubTag1><SubTag2></SubTag2></Tag1>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
Elements subTag2 = doc.getElementsByTag("SubTag2");
```

If there is only one element with the tag "SubTag2" you can get access to it like this:

```
subTag2.get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks @Xantipus, this was useful. I was using w3c.dom.document to parse, but I was unable to adapt the XML to what I want. Instead of it, I chose to create a new XML only with a few values that i need and create my own Tags. Thank anyway!